# Does an infected dental nerve affect nose breahting?

Tags: medications, dentistry, breathing, nerves, root-canal

I went to my dentist for a lookup and he told me I needed a tooth canal treatment. He asked me if I had some problems with my nose, like if it's closed or dry. He was right about it and he told me the nerve next to my teeth is causing the blocked nose. Now I'am asking you guys about it in details. Do you think an infected nerve next to my tooth would cause my nose to be dry ?
Thanks for you opinions